# How to format decimal values as percentages in FusionCharts?

Tags: fusioncharts

I'm rendering a FusionCharts line chart that represents a change of percentage value over time.

I'm providing the values of each data point in decimal format (that is 0.01 for 1% and so on).

FusionCharts seems to have rich capabilities for number formatting (see e.g. [the docs on number scaling](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/usage-guide/configuring-your-chart-number-format.html)) but I can't seem to figure out how to simply format the decimal values like 0.03 as percentages (3%).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format decimal values into percentage can be achieved thru Number Scaling. Using "numberScaleValue" and "numberScaleUnit", decimals [0.03] will be converted to 3%

```
`<chart numberScaleValue='.01' numberScaleUnit='%'..>`
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. In case someone else wonders, make sure you don't have formatNumberScale='0' in the chart attributes as it will prevent the above from having effect.